# Is there a generalized solution to the "Freshman's dream" of derivatives equation?

Tags: integration, derivatives

[Michael Penn shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYFJV3Fatqk) that $(f(x)g(x))^{\prime} = f^{\prime}(x) g^{\prime}(x)$ has solutions of the form

$$f(x) = C \exp{\int \frac{g^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)-g(x)}dx}$$

for a given function $g(x)$.

Taking a generalization of this freshman's dream to be

$$\left( \prod_{j=1}^n f_j (x)\right)^{\prime} = \left( \prod_{j=1}^n f_j^{\prime} (x)\right)$$

is there analogously a collection of formulae for constructing a solution?

---

- [Blackpenredpen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZH5rfWcR7l4) also considered the case of two functions.

Comment: The same sorts of steps will give a formula for $f_n$ in terms of the other $n-1$ functions. Is that all you're after, or something "prettier"?

Comment: Your equation is equivalent to $\sum_jf_j'/f_j=\prod_jf_j'/f_j$. "When is the sum also the product?" is a well-worn topic.